# How to get all elements of mobile in Katalon Studio..?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am automating Android App on Android emulator.

I am not able to get all elements of mobile but instead I am getting text of element rather than getting the element.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileDriverFactory
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver as AppiumDriver

AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = MobileDriverFactory.getDriver()
List <MobileElement> elements = driver.findElementsById("element-id")
```

Pls try this way, I'm using this way, hope they're what you need.